# Change the position of elements in cell array (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, position, cell-array

I have an initial cell array : cell={'AB' 'CD' 'EF'}. How could I generate all of the cellarrays which their elements are combined from the changing positions of each element in the initial cell array?

The expected output in this case should be:

```
          out1 = {'AB' 'CD' 'EF'}
          out2 = {'AB' 'EF' 'CD'}
          out3 = {'CD' 'AB' 'EF'}
          out4 = {'CD' 'EF' 'AB'}
          out5 = {'EF' 'AB' 'CD'}
          out6 = {'EF' 'CD' 'AB'}
```

Thank you !

Comment: See [`perms`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer inspired by [excaza's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142068/change-the-position-of-elements-in-cell-array-matlab/31142592#comment50294975_31142068)

```
perms(cell)
```